# Any way to save my poor, lonely question?

Tags: discussion, support, auto-delete

For several months I have had 5 questions, but I just noticed that I was now down to 4. I was able to go to the Data Explorer and find the Id of the missing question and undelete it, but I'm concerned it might not be permanent. It seems that said question recently got a couple inexplicable downvotes and [disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Anyway, I'm wondering if there's any way to prevent my question from being deleted every week (or whenever the question scavenger runs), or is my poor question doomed? Or perhaps it's a bad question and shouldn't be asked? Should simply I re-ask it every so often? Will protecting the question save it from the reaper?

Here's the question in question: [How to debug logon screensaver in Win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506318/how-to-debug-logon-screensaver-in-win7)

Comment: Have you considered offering a bounty to see if that attracts some answers?

Comment: And you can find a detailed explanation of the algorithm here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/149052

Comment: Was my link to the algorithm too subtle?

Comment: Ask the questions on Quora, where there is no dumb roomba.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to post a question about it on Meta, in order to attract more attention and hopefully upvotes. Oh - it seems you already did that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your question got picked up by the [automatic deletion rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/155160):

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has -1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

As you can see from that answer, the only things to do to prevent future automatic deletion is to have the question maintain a positive score. As I'm writing this, it's at +2, so it may be okay.

Either way, the question looks okay to me otherwise and I'm sorry to see you haven't received an answer. Do not repost your question periodically, but you can try drawing more attention to it by following the suggestions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions).

Comment: You're the second person to link him to something he already mentioned in the question

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It's one of my superpowers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why someone would downvote that.  I just upvoted it to help prevent it from getting a negative score b/c it looks like a perfectly good question to me :)

Anyway, with 30k reputation on SO it's my opinion that you've paid your dues and can ask whatever the hell you want.  If it gets deleted again I would say just ask it again.  Of course, I'll prolly get downvoted here for saying that!

Comment: High reputation isn't a license to post off-topic or otherwise poor questions. They will be closed and removed as needed. That's not an issue here, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear I cared about the rules more when I first joined, but after seeing how many moderator nazis on here close question for dumb reasons I've come to the point that I could care less about the rules.  So in my mind 30k reputation is a license to post an off topic question if you want ;)